# Styling Points of Vector Grid in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, style, vector-grid, popup

I am using the Leaflet Vector Grid Plugin to load a geojson innto my Leaflet project. But I can't figure out how to implement a popup and style the data by attributes.

I load up the data with following command:

```
 L.vectorGrid.slicer(data).addTo(map);
```

How can I implement my functions for the style:

```
 function Kategorie(feature, latlng) {
        switch(feature.properties["categorie"]) {
            case "1":
                var Icon1 = new L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'icons/1.png',
                    iconSize:     [15, 15], 
                    iconAnchor:   [5, 5], 
                    popupAnchor:  [10, 10] o
                });
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: Icon1});
```

and the function of the pop up:

```
  function popupcontent(feature, layer) {

                var popUp = "<h2>"+feature.properties.Name+"</h2>"  ;

                layer.bindPopup(popUp);}
```

I already studied the documentation of the plugin but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `style` function, as you did named `Kategorie`, for `vectorTileLayerStyles` option, use the `getFeatureId` function to get the `id` of each feature, and set `interactive : true`. The code below will guide you through the steps. Good luck.

```
var Kategorie = function (properties, zoom) {
... // as you have done above
}

var style = {
          rendererFactory: L.svg.tile, // L.canvas.tile
          vectorTileLayerStyles: {
            sliced: Kategorie
          },
          interactive: true,
          getFeatureId: function (f) {
          return f.properties['EventID'] // look for a unique ID in your data
          }
        }
```

Then get a control name for the `vectorlayer` rather than only adding it.

```
vectorgrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(data, style) // data is parsed GeoJSON
```

Then add an `on click` function:

```
      vectorgrid.on('click', function (e) {
      var properties = e.layer.properties
      var popUpText = Object.entries(properties)
        .map(function ([key, val]) {
          return `${key}: ${val}`
        })
        .join('<br>')
      L.popup()
        .setContent(popUpText)
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .openOn(map)
    })
    vectorgrid.addTo(map)
  })
```